# One question per post please

Tags: discussion, faq, policies, close-reasons, vote-to-close

#### If your post contains more than one question, or even looks like it contains more than one question, please do not be surprised if people click the following button:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this needs to be extended to include the guidance not to ask "new" questions in comments.